# Android-Volley-Multipart-Request

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data

I am trying to send some images and text to server using Android-Volley-Multipart-Request like shown here:
https://github.com/Ankit7791/Android-Volley-Multipart-Request

but not enough explanation.

Would be happy if I could get a good tutorial or explanation as to what I am doing wrong. Also, I am open to other library suggestions.

I modified it a little to handle my code below

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put(Utils.KEY_APPID, "j8Ue72@lfZy");
                params.put(Utils.KEY_APIKEY, "f9da8764b6d8c3413e5503d6bfe91e63");
                params.put(Utils.KEY_MOBILE, "0541778110");
                params.put(Utils.KEY_ORDERID, "Sam_100001");

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
                //for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
                params.put(Utils.Accept_signature, new DataPart(idImageCapture.getText().toString(), idImagebyteArray, "image/*"));
                params.put(Utils.Accept_receive, new DataPart(imageLocation.getText().toString(), locationImagebyteArray, "image/*"));
                params.put(Utils.Accept_location, new DataPart(signature.getText().toString(), signatureImagebyteArray, "image/*"));
                return params;
            }
        };
```

Not sure what the issue is

but I keep getting the below error:

android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception: string resource id #0xc8

Comment: try posting your full `logcat`errors

Answer (score 0):

try this for multipart request in [Volley](https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/upload-file-simplemultipartrequest-volley-android-f9ace8ec0dec). It will help you a lot and If any problem , comment here.